# Que significa for (;;) {} en java

Tags: java

por ejemplo que hace el   for (;;) {} aqui?
que significa los ;; dentro del for?

```
    double parseExpression() {
        double x = parseTerm();
        for (;;) {
            if      (eat('+')) x += parseTerm(); // addition
            else if (eat('-')) x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
            else return x;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

El uso de `;;` en la declaración de tu bucle, lo vuelve de caracter infinito; observa el siguiente par de ejemplos

**BUCLES INFINITOS**

A través del siguiente ejemplo, puedes observar que es para declarar un bucle infinito; pues no estas declarando ni la variable que se va a utilizar ni el contador ni mucho menos el límite a respetar

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(;;)
      {
          System.out.println("Hola");
      }
    }
}
```

También lo puedes ver del siguiente modo, declaras la variable a usar y un valor inicial y después el contador de aumento e igual será infinito

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int numero = 0;;numero++)
      {
          System.out.println(numero);
      }
    }
}
```